# Javascript in LWC in wire adapter not working as expected when parsing data

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, json

I need to edit a picklistvalues json to add another picklist value. I used the parse/stringify to make the json editable. I had it working in a sandbox, but when deployed to a scratchorg it seems that my parse/stringify doesn't work for some reason. data has all of the picklist info for the object. When trying to set pickListOptions it has no picklist info, empty.

Any idea why this would behave this way?

```
@wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: LINEITEM_OBJECT, recordTypeId: '$recordTypeId' })
getPickListOptions( {error, data}) {
    try {
        if (!!data) {
            this.pickListOptions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log('this.picklistOptions-------', this.picklistOptions);
            this.pickListOptions.picklistFieldValues.Body__c.values = [{attributes: null, label:"--None--", validFor: [], value: ""}, ...this.pickListOptions.picklistFieldValues.Body__c.values];
        } else if(!!error) {
            console.log('error----2---', JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('err---3----', JSON.stringify(err));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `that my parse/stringify doesn't work for some reason`?

Can you see the API invoked in the network tab of your browser? is the `data` brought back to your `getPickListOptions` method?

Comment: Does the `LINEITEM_OBJECT` have multiple record types? how are you selecting those?

Comment: this.picklistOptions is empty when a clone data using parse/stringify.

Comment: I get the RecordTypeId from the record